# "android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse" in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am constantly getting error:

> cannot resolve sumbol R.

I had used solution like clean,rebuild, sync with Gradle file. All of them not working.

Comment: you probably have an error in one of your layout files

Comment: Plz tell how to resolve it ...i am new to android.

Comment: fix the error in your layout file, you gave us not information so we cant help you aside from that

Comment: I recommend updating your Android Studio. Some of the earlier versions had annoying bugs like this that have since been fixed. The latest stable version of Android Studio is 1.3.2, and you should be able to update though the IDE (Help -> Check for updates on Windows, Android Studio -> Check for updates on Mac). That said, I can't guarantee this will fix your issue if you have errors in one of your layout files as @tyczj has said.

Comment: If you are using the Appcompat v23, check if you are compiling with api 23.